# Notification sound isn't changing from default, even after changing in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, notifications

I have been trying to change the sound of the notification but it isn't changing at all.
It is using the default notification in all cases, even when I have assigned the channel.
Please check the codes below and let me know, where I am going wrong.

### Created Notification Channel in Application class

```
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
              createNotificationChannel()
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val ordersChannelId = "Orders"
        val orderSoundUri =
            Uri.parse("android.resource://" + applicationContext + "/raw/ordernotification")
        val attributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM).build()
        val VIBRATE_PATTERN = longArrayOf(0,400,800,600,800,800,800,1000)


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val ordersChannel =
                NotificationChannel(ordersChannelId, "Orders", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            ordersChannel.apply {
                description = "This is Orders Channel"
                setSound(orderSoundUri, attributes)
                vibrationPattern = VIBRATE_PATTERN
                importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            }
            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(ordersChannel)
        }
    }
```

### Creating Notifications using FireBaseMessagingService

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
  
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.d("NotificationFire", "From: ${remoteMessage?.data}")
        val contentIntent = Intent(applicationContext, OrderInDetailActivity::class.java)
        val orderSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+applicationContext+"/raw/ordernotification")
        val attributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM).build()
        val VIBRATE_PATTERN = longArrayOf(0, 500)

        val contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext,
            0,
            contentIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
           
        remoteMessage?.data?.let {
            Log.d("NotificationFire", "Message Notification Data: ${it}")

            //Message Services handle notification

           val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "Orders")
               .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.biskit_logo)
               .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.data.toString())
               .setContentText(remoteMessage.data.toString())
               .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
               .setSound(orderSoundUri)
               .setVibrate(VIBRATE_PATTERN)
               .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
               .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
               .build()
            val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)
            Log.d("NotificationFire","Notification")
            notificationManager.notify(1,notification)
        }
```

This code is able to display notifications with the default sound only.

Comment: I don't remember fully, but is there an Android system setting to override this? i.e. if the user sets it to not allow custom notification noises?

Comment: `"android.resource://" + applicationContext + "/raw/ordernotification"` shouldn't your uri end in `.mp4` or whatever format you have?

Answer (score 0):

In your sound path you appended applicationContext. It will add some random value in your path. Instead you need to add the package name like this below.

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.FILE_NAME);//Here is FILE_NAME is the name of file that you want to play
```